# Input to Bidirectional LSTM in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Normally all inputs fed to BiLSTM are of shape `[batch_size, time_steps, input_size]`.

However, I'm working on a problem of Automatic Grading of an Essay in which there's an extra dimension called number of sentences in each essay. So in my case, a typical batch after embedding using `word2vec`, is of shape `[2,16,25,300]`.

Here, there are 2 essays in each batch `(batch_size=2)`, each essay has 16 sentences, each sentence is 25 words long`(time_step=25)` and I'm using word2vec of 300 dimensions `(input_size=300)`.

So clearly I need to loop this batch over dimension 16 somehow such that the shape of input becomes `[2,25,300]` in each iteration. I have tried for a long time but I haven't been able to find a way to do it. For example, if you make a loop over `tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn()`, it'll give error in second iteration saying that `tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn()` kernel already exists. I can't directly make a `for` loop over `sentence_dimension` because those are tensors of shape `[None,None,None,300]` and I gave values just for the sake of simplicity. If there any other way to do it? Thanks. Please note that I am not using `Keras` or any other framework.

Here's a sample encoding layer for reference.

```
def bidirectional_lstm(input_data):
    cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=200, state_is_tuple=True)
    outputs, states  = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw=cell,
                                                       cell_bw=cell,
                                                       dtype=tf.float32,
                                                       inputs=input_data)
    return tf.concat(outputs,2)
```

`embedded` is of shape `[2,16,25,300]`.

And here's a sample input

```
for batch_i, texts_batch in enumerate(get_batches(X_train, batch_size)): ## get_batches() is yielding batches one by one
  ## X_train is of shape [2,16,25] ([batch_size,sentence_length,num_words])

  ## word2vec
  embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(word_embedding_matrix, texts_batch)
  ## embeddings shape is now [2,16,25,300] ([batch_size,sentence_length,num_words,word2vec_dim])

  ## Now I need some kind of loop here to loop it over sentence dimension. Can't use for loop since these are all placeholders with dimensions None
  ## ??? output = bidirectional_lstm(embeddings,3,200,0.7) ??? This would be correct if there was no sentence dimension.
```

Comment: You could reshape your data into [2, 16*25, 300]. So your lstm get all the sentence from an essay at once. If you want a per sentence output in keras there is a layer wrapper TimeDistributed, in which you can wrap your bidriectional lstm layer. I noticed that you don't use keras but you can look at the code and see how it's done.

Comment: Reshaping is not possible because that would mean taking whole essay as a one big sentence which I can't do. I looked at the `TimeDistributed` source code but unfortunately it's too complex for me to understand. If anybody has anymore suggestions, please suggest. Thanks.